# Eclipse is crashing during debug on device (blackberry) with error "handheld is resetting: Error: myClass: Class removed."

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-jde, handheld

Sometimes when I run my project of Blackberry I got this error from the Eclipse:
"Handheld is resetting: Error: myClass: Class removed.

or this one:

"Handheld is resetting: Error: unable to open port.

After that the device is resetting itself and sometimes even the eclipse is crashed.

The situation is inconsistent.
Maybe someone can help or even just to tell me why or when it happen ?

[image]
[image]